# HTML File with xml and xmln declaration cannot be transformed

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml, xslt

I've generated a HTML file and the top html declaration looks like this:

```
<html xml:lang="de-CH" lang="de-CH" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

And then I try to convert it into a different format with this .Net 4 code:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();

proc.Load("Html_to_Sql.xslt");

fsHtmlXml = new FileStream(file.Name, FileMode.Create);

html = XmlReader.Create(file.FullName, settings);
proc.Transform(html, null, fsHtmlXml);
```

Unfortunately nothing happens as long as I have the xml, lang and xmlns attributes in the HTML.
Why is that?

Comment: You should post your XSLT; the problem most likely is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work via XML and XPath

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Xml.XPath;

public class TransformXML
{
    //This will transform xml document using xslt and produce result xml document
    //and display it

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XPathDocument myXPathDocument = new XPathDocument(sourceDoc);
            XslTransform myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(resultDoc, null);
            myXslTransform.Load(xsltDoc);
            myXslTransform.Transform(myXPathDocument, null, writer);
            writer.Close();
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader (resultDoc);
            Console.Write("**This is result document**\n\n");
            Console.Write(stream.ReadToEnd());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XSLT will need to refer to elements in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace.  You haven't posted your XSLT code yet, the the problem most likely lies in that file.

Answer (score 1):

The xmlns attribute specifies the namespace of the XML document. This works in much the same way as namespaces within C#, where two classes with the same name but different namespaces are considered to be completely different classes. Changing the XML namespaces means that your XSLT templates / XPath will not match.